# Using the aws-cdk-local package and Localstack to test Lambda and APIGateway

Tags: aws-cdk, localstack

Could someone tell me how to do the following.

I have created a Cloud Development Kit app which has an API Gateway and a Lambda function

I want to use  aws-cdk-local package and Localstack to test this locally

I have installed everything correctly and I can deploy my CDK app to Localstack

How do I get the endpoint to test the APIGateway. The endpoints I see in the console after using cdklocal deploy are not correct
Using something like http://localhost:4566/restapis/my-api-gateway-id/dev/ results in

```
<Error>
<Code>NoSuchBucket</Code>
<Message>The specified bucket does not exist</Message>
<BucketName>restapis</BucketName>
<RequestId>xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-6e8eEXAMPLE</RequestId>
</Error>
```

Any advice or comments on how to create the correct endpoint is most welcome.

Answer (score -1):

For anyone else it appears the url below works

```
http://localhost:4566/restapis/restapi-id/local/_user_request_/
```

points port 4566 is the port my localstack runs on.

Use

```
aws --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4566 apigateway get-rest-apis
```

To get the restapi id(s)